# D&D 4e monk Spider Technique

Tags: dnd-4e, monk, move-action

The monk's Spider Technique says:
You climb your speed. During this movement, you can move across overhanging surfaces, such as ceilings, but you fall if you end your turn on such a surface.

- Is this move action considered Climb Speed? I know it doesn't say so but the way the first sentence is stated makes it sound like there is no climb skill check necessary.
- Do you need a free hand for climbing this way?
- Is it possible to stop on a vertical wall and fight from there two-handed without penalty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It is not considered a climb speed.**

You merely climb at your speed, if it was a climb speed it would specify so (rules do only what they say; no more, no less). Thus you can't use Spider Technique as part of a charge.

**Climbing does not require a free hand**
I've checked the Compendium and nowhere does it mention needing a free hand to climb.

**There's nothing explicit in the rules about penalties for attacking while climbing**

As with the free question, the Athletics entry on the Compendium concerning climbing does not state that there is any penalty for making attacks while climbing on a vertical service.

Comment: Re: free hand, it's odd because part of the heavy/light shield distinction is having a free hand to climb...

Comment: @telandor please post that as its own question and I'll answer it as best I can.

Comment: @wax eagle I guess I'll have to ask my DM then...

Comment: @telandor You don't have to. The rules support what I posted, only bring it up if he first questions it. I fully suspect the descriptions of having the hand free to help climb for light shield is a holdover from previous editions. If you fall you need a free hand to catch yourself (so climbing without one could be risky), but it is doable RAW.

Comment: You mean "Catch Hold"? It doesn't say that you need a free hand. It sure would make sense though.
By the way, what does "RAW" mean?

Comment: @telandor yes I mean Catch hold and you are correct, I misremembered, you in fact do not need a free hand to do that either. RAW means Rules as Written, in contrast to, RAI, rules as interpreted. 4e is an explicitly RAW system because of how it uses keywords and its general rules about powers doing exactly what they say, nothing more, nothing less and "specific beats general" among other things. In 4e mechanics and story are separate whereas in other systems they co-mingle. RAW is what the rules say they mean taken as they are written, RAI implies designer's intent or DM fiat.